# Disable relaying of mails from specific IPs on Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

We have some copy machines in our network which have the ability to scan to mail. We would like to allow mailing only to the addresses in our domain and not to external addresses. There is no configuration possible on the copy machines, so it either has to be done with our Exchange 2007 Server or I could set up a new VM with Windows or Linux to accomplish this task.

Is there a way to block specific IPs from sending mails to external in Exchange 2007 (which will soon be upgraded to Exchange 2010) or do I have to setup a new SMTP server handling the requests from those copy machines? If the latter, what should I use and how do I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful article on [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277329.aspx) that provides exact details on how to configure the SMTP relaying options on your Microsoft Exchange server.

Subsequently, you can allow the photocopying/copier machines to transit email messages within the LAN environment through the restrictive options dictated in the documented article above.

I do hope that you will find the above information useful.

Comment: This article is only for Exchange 2000 and 5.5. Do you have one for 2007?